# Doit avoir été / a dû être

Tags: grammaire

Est-ce que les deux phrases sont correctes?

1. Le train de métro a dû être retardé.
2. Le train de métro doit avoir été retardé.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les deux phrases sont grammaticalement correctes. ***Doit avoir été*** et ***a dû être*** sont souvent synonymes et indiquent une supposition. *A dû être* peut aussi être une affirmation qui indique que le retard est intentionnel.

En revanche, *le train de métro* n'est pas une expression habituelle. Un métro est un type de train, mais *le train de métro*, jamais entendu. Je pense que tu veux dire ***la rame de métro*** ou simplement ***le métro***.

Comment: Ou simplement « le métro ».

Comment: Oui, je voulais dire *rame de métro*.

Comment: "Le train a du être retardé par le superviseur en raison d'un problème d'alimentation" est plus affirmatif que la phrase avec "doit avoir été retardé" qui est une supposition.

Comment: @Graffito Oui, *a dû être* peut être une supposition ou une affirmation contrairement à *doit avoir été* qui n'est que le premier, c'est vrai. Merci, je l'ajoute à ma réponse.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est marrant cette petite nuance sur l'affirmation qui n'est pas possible avec doit avoir été. Ça ne repose que sur l'inversion de avoir et devoir? Au présent, l'affirmation est possible avec la première expression: il doit être arrêté coûte que coûte. En fait, les deux expressions deviennent les mêmes au présent?

Comment: @Frank: C'est probablement la combinaison du modal (*devoir*) et de l'aspect accompli *du complément* qui fait que la phrase devient nécessairement une supposition. Le temps de la phrase (c'est-à-dire du modal lui-même) ne change rien. « Elle a dû avoir été modifiée avant qu'on s'en rende compte » est aussi une supposition.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez _elle a dû avoir été modifiée_: supposition. _Elle a dû être modifiée_: supposition ou affirmation. _Elle doit être modifiée_: affirmation ou supposition. _Elle doit avoir été modifiée_: plutôt _elle a dû être modifiée_: affirmation ou supposition. En fait, _elle a dû avoir été modifiée_ est un peu acrobatique.